# Ruby: Digest Proxy Authentication

Tags: ruby, proxy, digest-authentication

I'm behind proxy (digest auth).

Is there way to access web pages?

1. Httpclient - Basic and NTLM
2. Open-Uri - no Digest.

One more thing. I would like to install gems. There are BASIC in box only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No answers.
I found HTTParty, but it doesn't work.

Basic auth works (i use sniffer, it sends authorization request):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'pp'

class Rep
  include HTTParty
  http_proxy '192.168.5.12', 3128
  basic_auth 'user', 'password'
end

pp Rep.get('http://ya.ru')
```

But digest auth does not work (sniffer shows requests without any authorizations):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'pp'

class Rep
  include HTTParty
  http_proxy '192.168.5.12', 3128
  digest_auth 'user', 'password'
end

pp Rep.get('http://ya.ru')
```

There is an error?